# Calculation of limit of a a function

Tags: calculus

I was trying to calculate the limit of a function $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x e^{(ln x)^2}}{(x+1)^{\alpha +1}}$$ where $\alpha > 0$. First I tried L'Hospital's rule since it is of the form $(\infty / \infty )$, but it didn't work. Then I tried using Taylor series of exponential function, but still it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is equivalent (in the [asymptotic, Landau-notation sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations)) to
$$
\frac{xe^{\ln^2 x}}{x\cdot x^\alpha} = \frac{e^{\ln^2 x}}{e^{\alpha\ln x}}  = e^{(\ln x -\alpha)\ln x}
$$
when $x\to\infty$. Now, since $(\ln x -\alpha)\ln x \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} \infty$, can you conclude?

PS: Taylor series won't really work here (at least out-of-the-box), since the limit is for $x\to\infty$, not at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Applying  log gives $$ln(\frac{x e^{(ln x)^2}}{(x+1)^{\alpha +1}})=lnx+(lnx)^2-(\alpha+1)ln(x+1)$$ I will be a bit sloppy here and just assume that for large $x$, $lnx=ln(x+1)$. So we can rewrite above as $lnx(-\alpha+lnx)$ which goes to $\infty$ hence so does your original expression.